# Trying to count and return a number of rows in a table

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code to count the number of rows in a database and to return the result to a user:

```
// Connect to database and select
$mysqli = mysqli_connect($config['db_hostname'], $config['db_username'], $config['db_password'], $config['db_name']);
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
$select = 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS wines FROM  ft_form_4 WHERE feu_id = "'.$feuid.'"';
$response = mysqli_query($mysqli, $select) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($mysqli));
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($response, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$wines = (int)$result[wines];

echo $wines;

// Return 0 for no entries
if ($wines = 0) {

echo 'You currently have no wines entered, your current total entry fee is <strong>£0</strong>.';
}

elseif ($wines = 1) {

echo 'You currently have 1 wine entered, your current total entry fee is <strong>£135</strong>.';
}

elseif ($wines > 1) {

$fee = $wines * 135;
echo 'You currently have '.$wines.' wines entered, your current total entry fee is <strong>'.$fee.'</strong>.';
}
```

When I run the code, the result is echoed as 3 in the first bit (which I have just put in for testing) which is correct, but it always displays the second line, saying there is one wine entered and the entry fee is £135. It doesn't seem to recognise the 3 as a number.

I have tried a second lot of code using mysqli_num_rows, but I'm not having any luck with that either.

Comment: You're using `=`, which is the assignment operator, for a comparison. You should use `==` instead. `=` returns the value of the variable being assigned, so `if ($wines = 0)` returns false, but `if ($wines = 1)` returns true

Comment: I have tried that previously, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: And now it's mysteriously working… Thanks all who answered!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comparison is wrong, you should use `==` instead of `=`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a smarter approach?

```
$fee = $wines * 135;
echo 'You currently have '.($wines > 0 ? $wines : 'no').' wine'.($wines != 1 ? 's' : '').' entered, your current total entry fee is <strong>£'.$fee.'</strong>.';
```

Explained:

```
($wines > 0 ? $wines : 'no')
```

What we do, inside the parentheses, is that we evaluate the first part:

```
$wines > 0
```

If that is true, the value after the '?' (if) will be output, if false the value after ':' (else) will be output.

Same goes, finding out whether or not to echo the s in wine**s**:

```
($wines != 1 ? 's' : '')
```

If $wines == 1 we don't echo the s in wine**s**:

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a go, though I'm fairly new to programming and I like to do things I understand rather than just copying stuff!

Comment: @Badger That's the type of comments we like to hear, bravo +1

Answer (score 0):

```
elseif ($wines = 1) {
```

will always be true as you are assigning the value 1 to $wines, try:

```
elseif ($wines == 1) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the '==' comparator

```
// Return 0 for no entries
if ($wines == 0) {
    echo 'You currently have no wines entered, your current total entry fee is <strong>£0</strong>.';
}
elseif ($wines == 1) {
    echo 'You currently have 1 wine entered, your current total entry fee is <strong>£135</strong>.';
}
elseif ($wines > 1) {
    $fee = $wines * 135;
    echo 'You currently have '.$wines[0].' wines entered, your current total entry fee is <strong>'.$fee.'</strong>.';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "==" instead of "="

```
 if ($wines == 1) {
```

As, `==` is comparison operator and a single `=` will just assign the value `1` to `$wines`.